# ramdisk, how to clean every x min files older than X min

Tags: cron, cache, tmpfs, disk-cleanup

To setup a cron job to purge outdated cache files that are more than 8 minutes old every 10 minutes on disk its an easy task.

```
# crontab -e
*/10 * * * * root find /tmp/diskcache -type f -mmin +8 -delete 2>/dev/null
```

The problem is if i want to move diskcache to tmpfs. My idea with tmpfs (otherwise tmpfs eat half ram of default) is:

```
/etc/fstab
tmpfs   /dev/diskcache     tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,size=2G      0  0
```

The new command will be (correct?):

```
# crontab -e
*/10 * * * * root find /dev/diskcache -type f -mmin +8 -delete 2>/dev null
```

Is it the best approach right now ? And most important, is it correct ? Thanks :)

```
Filesystem        1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/ploop39151p9  41151808 634408  38420352   2% /
devtmpfs            3145728      0   3145728   0% /dev
tmpfs               3145728      0   3145728   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               3145728     32   3145696   1% /run
tmpfs               3145728      0   3145728   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Answer (score 0):

It would work.

However, the /dev directory is typically meant for device files. If you don't want /tmp to be a tmpfs, just the directory "diskcache", you could mount a tmpfs at /tmp/diskcache.

An alternative to a cronjob every ten minutes might be to set up a filesystem watcher for that directory that spawns a process for each file created there that sleeps for 8 minutes and then removes that file. Like so:

```
inotifywait -m -e create --format %f /tmp/diskcache | while read newfile; do ( sleep $((8*60)) && rm -f "${newfile}" )& done
```

HTH